# PyTorch Lightning: includes some Tensor objects in checkpoint file

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

As Pytorch Lightning provides automatic saving for model checkpoints, I use it to save top-k best models. Specifically in Trainer setting,

```py
    checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
                            monitor='val_acc',
                            dirpath='checkpoints/',
                            filename='{epoch:02d}-{val_acc:.2f}',
                            save_top_k=5,
                            mode='max',
                            )
```

This is working well but it does not save some attribute of the model object. My model stores some Tensor at every training epoch end such that

```py
class SampleNet(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.save_hyperparameters()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(100, 1)
        self.loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropy()

        self.some_data = None # Initialize as None

    def training_step(self, batch):
        x, t = batch
        out = self.layer(x)
        loss = self.loss(out, t)
        results = {'loss': loss}

        return results

    def training_epoch_end(self, outputs):
       
        self.some_data = some_tensor_object
```

This is a simplified example but I want the checkpoint file made by above `checkpoint_callback` to remember the attribute `self.some_data` but when I load the model from checkpoint, it always reset to `None`. I confirmed that it is successfully updated during the training.

I tried not to initialize it as None in `init` but then the attribute will disappear when loading model.

Saving the attribute as a distinct `pt` file is something I want to avoid as it is associated with model configuration so I manually need to match the file with corresponding checkpoint file later.

Would it be possible to include such tensor attribute in checkpoint file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the model class hooks `on_save_checkpoint()` and `on_load_checkpoint()` for all sorts of objects that you want to save alongside the default attributes.

```
def on_save_checkpoint(self, checkpoint) -> None:
    "Objects to include in checkpoint file"
    checkpoint["some_data"] = self.some_data

def on_load_checkpoint(self, checkpoint) -> None:
    "Objects to retrieve from checkpoint file"
    self.some_data= checkpoint["some_data"]
```

[See module docs](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/lightning_module.html#on-load-checkpoint)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible directly, as to extract the parameters most likely [`nn.Module.state_dict()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict) is used.
This methods only extracts the values of the tensors that are actually considered as parameters. So in this case a workaround would be saving your data as a parameter (see [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.parameter.Parameter.html)):

```
self.some_data = torch.nn.parameter.Parameter(your_data)
```